# Maven deploy:deploy-file removes extension from file

Tags: java, maven, deployment, maven-deploy-plugin

I am trying to deploy signature files separately using `deploy-file` goal to Nexus staging repository, but I noticed that mvn deploy plugin removes the extension. My file is something like: `azerty-0.1.jar.asc`

but the file that gets deployed is: `azerty-0.1.asc`

I tried adding a classifier: `-Dclassifier=jar`

the file that gets deployed is: `azerty-0.1-jar.asc`

This seems like a strange behaviour.

**Question**: Any ideas how to work around it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is rather a normal behavior, Maven is using the file extension as artefact `packaging`, from `maven-deploy-plugin`, [`deploy-file`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html), [`packaging`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html#packaging) option:

> Type of the artifact to be deployed. Retrieved from the `<packaging>` element of the POM file if a POM file specified. **Defaults to the file extension** if it is not specified via command line or POM.

Note: bold is mine.

Moreover, the `classifier` option would indeed add an `-` between the version and the string provided as classifier: that's maven [convention](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates).

In your case you want to specify a special `packaging`, which would be `jar.asc` if you really want the remote file to have as extension `jar.asc`.

The following would hence work:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dfile=azerty-0.1.jar.asc -Dpackaging=jar.asc -DrepositoryId=your_id -Durl=http://your_repository -DgroupId=your_groupId -DartifactId=azerty -Dversion=0.1
```

Note the `-Dpackaging=jar.asc` which effectively tells Maven the file extension would be `jar.asc`.

---

As a general note, if you are using the repository as a build store, that would still be reasonable, otherwise in your case you would push to a Maven repository an artifact which would then be difficult (or rather weird) to import in a project.

If instead this is really an additional artifact of your project, you should look at the [`attach-artifact`](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/attach-artifact-mojo.html) goal of the `build-helper-maven-plugin`, to effective define it as additional artifact, then Maven will automatically add it to its `install` and `deploy` phase.